# Windows and Python Paths

Tags: python, path

I am trying import a module called arnold but am having some trouble. I appened my python path with

```
:C:\solidangle\mtoadeploy\2017\scripts\arnold
```

When I print out my python path with

```
 os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

I get:

```
['C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2016\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages:C:\\solidangle\\mtoadeploy\\2017\\scripts\\arnold']
```

I also tried to remove the arnold from the path since there are other folders there. No dice. I also tried assigning it to my path variable. No dice there as well.

Within the arnold dir there is an **init** file importing all the modules in the folder.

Anything i'm missing here?

Comment: How exactly did you append your PYTHONPATH? I think there may be the problem

Comment: I went to my system properties->Environment Variables->Selected the System Variable-> then clicked edit. For the Path variable, i created a new row in the UI and added the path. For the PYTHONPATH I clicked edit and appened : then the path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use the wrong path separator. On Windows you should use `;`, not `:` to separate several paths.